# appfuse: Embedded error: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'x' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, database, jdbc, appfuse

appfuse: Embedded error: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'x' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify a value for that column in sample-data.xml